# Use of softmax with tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow

Is it necessary to use tf.nn.softmax() to get the softmax of logits before using `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits()`?

I am doing binary classification on an imbalanced set, and have my `pos_weight` value set to [1.0, 15.0] to compensate for the latter class being underrepresented in the data.

The other similar op `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` explicitly says not to use softmax beforehand, but the weighted version does not specify.  I have tried it both with and without, and when I use the softmax before the model does not learn (e.g. AUC converges to `0.500`).

The last layer in my model is using elu activation on a `[batch_size, 2]` tensor.  My labels are coded as `[1, 0]` for the first class, and `[0, 1]` for the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use tf.nn.softmax() to get the softmax of logits before using tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits()?

You shouldn't because [`weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228001302/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) applies the sigmoid to the targets.

You can see that in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd7f1f4955cee1df4f6dbd0baba783fbcf845bc3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L222-L242):

```
def weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(targets, logits, pos_weight, name=None):
  """Computes a weighted cross entropy.

     For brevity, let `x = logits`, `z = targets`, `q = pos_weight`.

    The loss is:
    qz * -log(sigmoid(x)) + (1 - z) * -log(1 - sigmoid(x))
  = qz * -log(1 / (1 + exp(-x))) + (1 - z) * -log(exp(-x) / (1 + exp(-x)))
  = qz * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (-log(exp(-x)) + log(1 + exp(-x)))
  = qz * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (x + log(1 + exp(-x))
  = (1 - z) * x + (qz +  1 - z) * log(1 + exp(-x))
  = (1 - z) * x + (1 + (q - 1) * z) * log(1 + exp(-x))

  Setting `l = (1 + (q - 1) * z)`, to ensure stability and avoid overflow,
  the implementation uses
  (1 - z) * x + l * (log(1 + exp(-abs(x))) + max(-x, 0))

    """
    # The logistic loss formula from above is
    #   (1 - z) * x + (1 + (q - 1) * z) * log(1 + exp(-x))
    # For x < 0, a more numerically stable formula is
    #   (1 - z) * x + (1 + (q - 1) * z) * log(1 + exp(x)) - l * x
    # To avoid branching, we use the combined version
    #   (1 - z) * x + l * (log(1 + exp(-abs(x))) + max(-x, 0))
    log_weight = 1 + (pos_weight - 1) * targets
    return math_ops.add(
        (1 - targets) * logits,
        log_weight * (math_ops.log1p(math_ops.exp(-math_ops.abs(logits))) +
                      nn_ops.relu(-logits)),
        name=name)
```

FYI [Softmax vs Sigmoid function in Logistic classifier?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254071/12359)